# R: How do I merge data frames based on one exact match and one nearest (date) match?

Tags: r, merge, match

**The real life problem:** I have test results from blood draws from research volunteers. I want to merge these results with demographic and survey data from the volunteers, but many of them came in for multiple studies on different dates (spanning years). So the survey data row must match the test result subject id exactly and be as close as possible to the blood draw date (might be exact or off by days or weeks). Also, some subjects have multiple blood test results from different blood draw dates.

**The toy example:**

```
set.seed(905)  

#The "test result" data frame:
df.1 <- tibble(id = c('A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A3'),
           draw.date = as.Date(c("2013-01-19", "2015-03-22", "2013-01-19",
                               "2014-04-23", "2016-05-07")),
           result1 = rnorm(5))  

#The "survey results" data frame:
df.2 <- tibble(id = c('A1', 'A1', 'B1', 'A2', 'A3'),
           test.date = as.Date(c("2013-02-01", "2015-02-28", "2017-01-26",
                               "2014-04-23", "2016-05-06")),
           survey1 = 101:105,
           survey2 = letters[1:5])  

#The desired final data frame:
desired <- tibble(id = df.1$id,
              draw.date = df.1$draw.date,
              result1 = df.1$result1,
              test.date = as.Date(c("2013-02-01", "2015-02-28", "2014-04-23",
                                  "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06")),
              survey1 = c(101, 102, 104, 105, 105),
              survey2 = c('a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'e'))
```

**Commentary:**
I'm having trouble getting R to find the closest date within only those who have matching IDs.  In other words, preventing it from checking the draw.date against all test.dates and limiting it to only test.dates with a matching ID.

I've searched through previous questions, but none of them have duplicate IDs (primary match variable) in both data frames with different dates (secondary match variable). I haven't been able to find anything that works for me.

I would prefer a dplyr solution, but am open to anything that works. I'm not familiar with the data.table package, so if that's my only option, walk me through it slowly :)

Note: My real life df.1 is 1524 obs x 22 vars and df.2 is 26802 obs x 7317 vars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr` approach could be

```r
library(dplyr)

df.1 %>%
  left_join(df.2, by = "id") %>%
  mutate(date_diff = abs(difftime(draw.date, test.date, units = "days"))) %>%
  group_by(id, draw.date) %>%
  filter(date_diff == min(date_diff)) %>%
  select(-date_diff)
```

which gives

```
  id    draw.date  result1 test.date  survey1 survey2
1 A1    2013-01-19   2.92  2013-02-01     101 a      
2 A1    2015-03-22  -0.349 2015-02-28     102 b      
3 A2    2013-01-19   0.382 2014-04-23     104 d      
4 A3    2014-04-23   0.308 2016-05-06     105 e      
5 A3    2016-05-07  -0.843 2016-05-06     105 e
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved using a *rolling join* to "nearest" which is available with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)   # version 1.11.4 used
setDT(df.2)[, draw.date := test.date][setDT(df.1), on = .(id, draw.date), roll = "nearest"]
```

> ```
>    id  test.date survey1 survey2  draw.date    result1
> 1: A1 2013-02-01     101       a 2013-01-19  2.9201353
> 2: A1 2015-02-28     102       b 2015-03-22 -0.3485295
> 3: A2 2014-04-23     104       d 2013-01-19  0.3824341
> 4: A3 2016-05-06     105       e 2014-04-23  0.3077772
> 5: A3 2016-05-06     105       e 2016-05-07 -0.8427319
> ```

For comparison, here is OP's expected result:

```
desired
```

> ```
>    id  draw.date    result1  test.date survey1 survey2
> 1: A1 2013-01-19  2.9201353 2013-02-01     101       a
> 2: A1 2015-03-22 -0.3485295 2015-02-28     102       b
> 3: A2 2013-01-19  0.3824341 2014-04-23     104       d
> 4: A3 2014-04-23  0.3077772 2016-05-06     105       e
> 5: A3 2016-05-07 -0.8427319 2016-05-06     105       e
> ```